# I can't visualize a table in an oracle base that is in a container from java

Tags: java, oracle, docker

Good afternoon,
I am having a rather strange problem. I cannot visualize from Java a table that is in an Oracle database, mounted with a Docker container. From SQL Developer I can connect and everything normal, I visualize my table, but when doing it from java I get an error that the table is not found:

Main Class:

```java
package BaseDeDatos;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Conexion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyConexion conexion=new MyConexion();
        ResultSet resultado;
        String cedula,nombre, apellido;

        resultado=conexion.getQuery("Select * from Cliente");

        try {
            while(resultado.next()){
                cedula = resultado.getString("cedula");
                nombre = resultado.getString("nombre");
             //   apellido = resultado.getString("apellido");

                System.out.println("Nombre: "+cedula+"\nRut: "+nombre);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My configuration to access the database

```java
package BaseDeDatos;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MyConexion {

    private String user = "cesar";
    private String password = "xxxxxxx123";

    static String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.164.7.203:1521/ORCLPDB1.localdomain";
    private Connection conn = null;

    public MyConexion() {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

            if (conn != null) {
                System.out.println("Conexion a base de datos " + url + " . . . Ok");
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Hubo un problema al intentar conecarse a la base de datos" + url);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error... " + ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Consultas a la Base de Datos.
     * 
     * @param _query
     * @return
     */
    public ResultSet getQuery(String _query) {
        Statement state = null;
        ResultSet resultado = null;
        try {
            state = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
            resultado = state.executeQuery(_query);
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultado;
    }
}
```

When I try to connect from java:

[image]

Performing the query in SQL Developer:

[image]

Details of my correct connection with SQL Developer:

[image]

When running:

```sql
select owner, table_name from all_tables where table_name = 'CLIENTE';
select * from dba_tab_privs where table_name = 'CLIENTE' and privilege = 'SELECT';
```

[image]

What could it be? I do not understand

Comment: Your SQL Developer connection is connecting as SYSDBA? That is not recommended. What do these return? `select owner, table_name from all_tables where table_name = 'CLIENTE';
select * from dba_tab_privs where table_name = 'CLIENTE' and privilege = 'SELECT';`

Comment: How should I connect according to your friend recommendation? I had to give him that privilege to be able to create the user inside the container

Comment: already place what the query returns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle errors can sometimes be misleading. You also get this Oracle error code...

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

when the table does exist but the user does not have permission to access the table.
In other words user `cesar` does not have access to database table `CLIENTE`.

By the way, according to what you posted, it appears there are two `CLIENTE` tables. One in the `SYS` schema and one in the `SYSTEM` schema. [This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/405/what-is-the-difference-between-sys-and-system-accounts-in-oracle-databases) *Stack Exchange* Q&A describes the difference between the schemas and also advises not to create user tables in these schemas. Hence I would recommend creating table `CLIENTE` in `cesar` schema. Then you won't get ORA-00942 error. If you can't do that then you need to grant access to table `CLIENTE` to user `cesar` like so

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON CLIENTE TO cesar
```

Note that you need to execute the above statement as the owner of the table, e.g. first connect to the database as `SYSTEM` and then execute the above statement. Remember that user `cesar` then needs to access the table as `SYSTEM.CLIENTE`.

```sql
select * from SYSTEM.CLIENTE
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it helped me to understand a little more how oracle databases works

Answer (score 0):

So kfinity's comment should have been pointed you to what really happened. But here is the explanation what I suspect.

You connected to the database as SYSDBA when you created the `CLIENTE` table. As a result this table is own by the system user. Given this with your SYSDBA connection you are able to see the table content.

The Java application does not connect as SYSDBA but rather as an ordinary user caesar. As a result all your selects running from Java will be executed against caesar schema where of course the table `CILENTE` does not exist.

To fix this just recreate the table and populate it with data into caesar schema.

Hope it helps.